# Primefaces galleria handle on complete load

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have a simple primefaces galleria

```
<p:galleria id="test-gallery" value="#{testController.imageIds}" var="item" autoPlay="false" >  
    <p:graphicImage width="300" value="#{imageStreamer.image}" >
        <f:param name="id" value="#{item}" />
    </p:graphicImage>
</p:galleria>
<script>alert("done");</script>
```

Everything is working fine but i am trying to call a javascript function only after the primefaces galleria has already loaded. On my code snipit above, it calls the alert even tho the galleria has not yet loaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well do your javascript after the page is finished loading:

```
<script> 
    $(window).load(function() {
        alert("Hello");             
    });
</script>
```

Comment: i guess this will do, unless there's a better way in handling the primefaces galleria loading complete